Why screenshots are being saved in moved folder?
In my work system of Windows 11, I moved the contents of the default Pictures folder into D: drive from C: drive. I tried to take a screenshot by the Win+Prt Scn shortcut, it took the screenshot but saved it to D: drive. What I want is the D: drive not to change, I want all screenshots to be saved into the Screenshots folder inside the Pictures folder of C: drive. I have another question, why it happened though-Save of screenshots in D drive? I was expecting that system will create a new folder in C drive and save the screenshots there.
Edit:
As suggested by @LPChip, even if I try to follow the steps. I get the following alerts.

The thing is that I don't want to move all the files from my D: drive. Instead I want my new screenshots to being saved in C: drive which is not happening as of now. Hope I'm clear now.

Did you move just the contents of the Pictures folder, or did you move the folder itself?

@DavidZ I moved the contents only i.e. folders like Screenshots, Camera etc. I didn't move the folder itself.

When you moved the pictures folder, you specified that your pictures folder is the on the D drive. Screenshots save to your pictures folder, so it is logical that it is saved in the D drive.
To solve your problem, execute the following steps:

Go to the Pictures folder on your D drive.
Right-click the folder, properties
In the location tab, click Restore default.
Hit apply.
A popup will ask you if you want to move all the files to the new location.
Decline this.


As I clearly mentioned I didn't move the Pictures folder. I moved the contents only.

Your screenshot states that my answer is still correct. After you set reset to default, you get the popup to move the files, click no and press ok to move out, problem should now be solved according to what you wish.
